# How to remove Express Checkout button from checkout page on Shopify basic plan?

Tags: shopify, checkout, express-checkout

I want to remove the express checkout option from my checkout page on Shopify basic plan.

Answer (score 7):

1. In your admin, go to online store > themes
2. Then Action > Edit code
3. Inside cart.liquid file, paste this at the top:

   ```css
   <style>
   .additional-checkout-buttons {
     display: none;
   }
   </style>
   ```
4. Inside cart.liquid file, paste this anywhere:

   ```
   {% if additional_checkout_buttons %}
       <div class="additional-checkout-buttons">
         {{ content_for_additional_checkout_buttons }}
       </div>
   {% endif %}
   ```
5. Save

Done! Why? Because Shopify is designed to show the express checkout whether on cart page OR checkout page NOT both. So if you add it to cart page (and hide it with CSS) then it will not appear on checkout page! :)

Please see the image of what I have on my site[image: remove shopify express checkout from checkout page]

Comment: Doesn't work with Brooklyn theme. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems that this solution is no longer working with new versions of shopify as that specific template no longer exists. Is there an updated solution for this?